# Working with Theano and Lasagne AttributeError

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, lasagne, nolearn

Now i'm working with then and lasagne. I have .csv input file with named emotions, and coordinates of them on photo. I'n trying to teach neural net to understand emotion by coordinates. When i'm parsing .csv file to then variables, and giving it to neural net, it says

```
AttributeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nolearn-0.6a0.dev0-py2.7.egg/nolearn/lasagne/base.py:504"  at index 0(0-based)', "'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'")
```

I'm tried to reshape data, but it gives me another errors(i think, that i do something wrong).
Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/RAhPpLuw
Here is train data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yeik1zum7z0iwm4/train1.csv?dl=0